# How can I detect the width of my screen which can be used on CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am having simple div

```
<div>test</div>
```

I want to apply width in pixels for some test purposes
I know that I can write this CSS so the width of the div will be expanded to the end of the whole screen

```
div {
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

but I want that width to be in pixels. So in order to find out the screen of my width i searched on google
and I can do that with the screen API
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_screen_width

it gives me 1536px. The problem is that when I set 1536px width of my div, the div length goes more than my screen, it creates horizontal scroll bar so the width should be less.

so how can I detect the actual width screen so the div will "end" right until the end of my screen without creation horizontal scroll bar ?

I tried this

```
body { 
   margin:0px;
}

div {
    width: 1536px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: You have a border around the div, which will make it 2px wider. Will 1534px work? Also, why do you need it to be in pixels? We might help you make further help, if we know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Assuming w3schools is correct on how to find the screen width ... you _are_ getting "the actual width screen". But the browser itself uses some of that width; edges of the browser window, possibly a scrollbar, sidebars, etc.  Maybe you want to get `window.innerWidth` in javascript.  Also: "but I want that width to be in pixels" — _why?_

Comment: You can also try elem.offsetWidth which includes padding and borders.

Comment: As others have said, please explain your reasoning for using pixels. By using viewport units, you can easily stretch the width of the screen, e.g. "width: 100vw". Viewport = the browser window size.

Comment: @SteffenAndreasKloster Hello, it is for test purpses, playing around and learn... btw I used box-sizing border box so everything will be calculated automatically, and 1534 does not work also...

Comment: @StephenP btw I am having empty html document so other things are not taken into consideration for my screen width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly: do not do it. However, if you really need to, here you are (tip: use `window.innerWidth` rather than ~`screen.width`~)

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let width =  window.innerWidth; // diff here, was: screen.width
  window['$container'].innerHTML =  width + "px";
  window['$container'].style.width = width + "px";
}, 100)
```

```css
div {
  width: unset;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { 
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="$container">test</div>
```

other keywords: DOM resize event, `getBoundingClientRect()`, container media queries, box-sizing border-box and - finally - outline vs border